# Изменить профиль (Локация не сохраняется для "всех публичных сообществ")

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника, локация

Когда заходишь на профиль, чтоб изменить данные, и потом выбираешь "сохранить везде"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

локация (Откуда) не сохраняется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделала несколько тестов (не все проверила (имя, ссылки итд)), НО заметила, что данные меняются => (раздел о себе), а именно локация не меняется почему то

проще говоря, чтоб изменить раздел "откуда", надо зайти на все сообщества и вручную поменять, незнаю было ли так и раньше, ни разу не меняла локацию, но вот личная информация, если меняешь для всех сообществ везде всегде обновлялась одновременно одинаково.

Comment: Такое лучше на MSE писать. Здесь нет ни разработчиков, не КМов SE. Что здесь обсуждать, судя по тегу?

Comment: @aepot я не оч разбираюсь в тегах на Мете.

Comment: Я всегда ставлю "обсуждение"

Comment: На MSE есть тег bug.

Comment: Я не знать инглиш

Comment: Простите, я думал что все разработчики знают, хотя-бы на уровне чтобы оформить багрепорт.

Comment: Не оч понимаю можно или нет дефект ставить, может так было задумано.... Может только у меня не работает...

Comment: Если так задумано, дефект закрывается с меткой "так-задумано".

Comment: Я могу конечно багрепортнуть и вы правы на это уровень англ хватит, но вдруг это так задумано, вдруг только у меня....

Comment: Хм, ок, попробую, первый багрепорт будет.... На выходных займусь

Comment: Похоже, что [год назад работало](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387736/339911)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHufn.gif   ===>     https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429537/update-location-for-all-public-communities-doesnt-save-worked ===> (❁´◡`❁)

Comment: Только вот сайт для бага всё ещё не тот. Надо было [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: По идее можно флагом на вопросе попросить модераторов его перенести (мигрировать) на MSE.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, о какой ссылке речь.

Comment: Meta StackExchange (MSE) - это о ВСЕХ сайтах сети (сейчас их 183), а Meta StackOverflow (MSO) - только об одном - английском StackOverflow. Поэтому, если проблема/предложение актуально для двух и более сайтов сети, то её логичнее публиковать на MSE. Но так как enSO самый большой сайт сети, то часто люди просто пишут на MSO, и не ходят на MSE. Из-за этого частенько появляются межсайтовые дубли (одинаковые вопросы на разных Meta-сайтах). Если дублей ещё нет или их просто не нашли, то предпочтительным вариантом является перенос (миграция) вопроса на MSE, как более общий сайт для проблем ВСЕЙ сети

Comment: @αλεχολυτ флагнула https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA99g.png

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398653/save-and-copy-changes-to-all-public-communities-only-updates-the-location-on-t

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315252/location-wasnt-copied-to-other-sites-after-pressing-save-and-copy-changes-to-a